# Is it Possible to Install face_recognition in python 2.7 rather than python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I tried to install face recognition in python 2.7.but i am getting the below error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIExe.png)

Comment: It is best to explain in detail how did you install it (or tried to), with which commands, and also the error as text, not as an image. This way it is more probable to get a better answer. To copy text from cmd, click the top left corner, then the edit menu and then either mark to select what you want to copy or just select all. Then with the enter key it will be copied.

Comment: thanks for nice information.soon i will change this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install CMake from the below given link and then try again? It seems CMake which is needed to build the dlib extension is missing on your system.

You can download and install CMake from here:
https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: i am getting the same error even i installed Cmake.Is there any other way

Comment: In case the above solution doesn't work, you can try these solutions posted on official dlib GitHub repo itself: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/218

Comment: Try this: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible ., python 2.7 provide more features to face recognition than python 3.5 version 
we can use pip installer to install all of the packages andexecute it